# Trying to force a refresh of most up to date image, after new image uploaded, using MVC3/Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC3, Razor, C#, EF4.1, MSSQL2008

I have implemented a mechanism to upload files to a web server "Uploads" folder.

The issue I have is that when the user is returned to the "Upload" view, the image is still the old one. This may be linked to the fact that I am using the PK of the User's Organisation as the filename ie 100.png. So swapping the image will produce another 100.png, ie overwrite the original. This prevents lots of rubbish files if I used a GUID instead. However the browser thinks nothing has changed so loads it, I guess, out of cache.

My razor code is:

```
    if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + strImageFileName)))
    {
        <p><img alt="Current Image" src="@Href("~/Uploads/" + strImageFileName)"/> </p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p><img alt="Current Image" src="@Href("~/Uploads/NoImageFile.png")"/> </p>
    }
```

If I get this issue, then a Shift Refresh usually does the job, although I would like this to be automatic. Is there a way to force a refresh, via code, so the newest Image is always shown. We did seem to have more issues with Chrome for some reason.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the url referenced by the link seems to be a lightweight solution over using AJAX.

http://www.immense.net/force-update-cached-files-images-favicon/

by adding something arbitrary like a version number. The browser will update the cashed image with the current version.

```
<img alt="Current Image" src="@Href("~/Uploads/" + strImageFileName + Version )"
```

you might want to use an action to return the image over a direct url to the image. If you are not already doing so.

Comment: Thanks for this and the link. As a result I solved it as :  + "?ver=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")